# How do I sum column after count in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I used below query

```
SELECT COUNT(client_mac) AS total_users 
FROM `social_user` 
WHERE social_network ='TWuser' 
GROUP BY client_mac HAVING total_users > 1
```

after run this query I got this result

[Please click here to see my result](http://prntscr.com/55jkrv)

But I need to SUM my 'total_users' column so my output should be

`total_users: **49**`

Sorry for my English and I don't have enough reputation to attach image that's why I added link

Comment: Provide some sample table data or create a fiddle.

Comment: Please have a look
here is my sample table link: http://awesomescreenshot.com/06f3tz1bc9

Comment: Why are you using a group by if you want the total users?

Comment: just select SUM(src.total_users) from(your select query) AS src

Comment: @MobasherFasihy
Thank you sir. Its working :)

Comment: @USER3533244 You are welcome! so please mark the comment as useful response.

Comment: Please sir one more question
if I want result like this-
FBuser: 12
TWuser: 49
LIuser: 5
using a single query so what i should to modify?

Comment: @user3533244 You can do that but you are running two queries when you only need one.  It is quite inefficient to do that.

Comment: @Devon
Could you please give me the solution, if possible?

Comment: @user3533244 I think you are misunderstanding what count() does.  All count(client_mac) is doing is counting the number of rows that match the group by.  So it is counting the number of clients that match each possible client_mac entry.  The HAVING in your query is only getting rid of the rows with a unique client_mac, not a client_mac value of <1.

Comment: @user3533244 you want to have count of each user in separate columns inside result?

Comment: @Devon I do not want to get them whose client_mac is once in my db.
I just want to get returning users

Comment: @user3533244 Exactly, so your query now is not doing what you want.  That is why you use WHERE not GROUP BY like I suggested in my answer's comment.

Comment: @Devon
could you please pest your expert query here?

Comment: @MobasherFasihy
Yes sir

Comment: @user3533244 I have added an updated query in my answer which I think is what you want

Comment: @Devon
excuse me please, may be i can not clear myself to you. I need which client_mac is more than one time exist in my db my client_mac field is not unique

Comment: @Devon What is 'count_mac' there is no field in my table named 'count_mac'

Comment: @user3533244 if you use two query then select(SUM(src.total_users),src.client_mac) from(select count(client_mac) as total_user,client_mac where social_network = 'TWuser') AS src GROUP BY src.client_mac

Comment: @user3533244 Okay, after reviewing the information you provided, I think my answer covers what you are looking for using a subquery join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally understand what you're after.

```
SELECT social_network, count(*) as total_users
FROM social_user
INNER JOIN  (
  SELECT client_mac FROM social_user
  GROUP BY client_mac HAVING count(*) > 1
) as src ON src.client_mac = social_user.client_mac
GROUP BY social_network
```

So the subquery should get all the client_macs that are repeated then the query will organize each entry by social network.

The problem I foresee is if a client_mac exists for more than one social network.

Comment: Thank you sir, I just changed "IS IN" to "IN". It is working fine :)

Thanks... (y)

Comment: @user3533244 Actually, I modified it.  Using an INNER JOIN instead of the WHERE IN seems to work better.

Comment: @user3533244 When you get to test out the query and confirm it does what you want, please accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you

```
select count(client_mac) as total_user,client_mac 
from social_user
where social_network = 'TWuser'
GROUP BY client_mac`
```

This query will bring total for each user not all user. fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11157/5)

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'src.total_users' in 'field list'

Comment: @user3533244 i wrote total_users not total_user now check.

Comment: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @user3533244 now check the query.

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle,  I used that to verify my code.  Because he needs the to check the number of times client_mac is repeated, a subquery is needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This query -

```
SELECT SUM(total_users) as total_usr_sum from (SELECT COUNT(client_mac) AS total_users FROM `social_user` WHERE social_network ='TWuser' GROUP BY client_mac HAVING total_users > 1) as sum
```

Comment: Did you tried this, This query showing the same result, you are expected and mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `COUNT(client_mac)` with `SUM(total_users)` in your query